# Java use result from recursive void function, add each to list and return in another function

Tags: java, list, recursion, void

I am using a modified version of a recursion algorithm I stumbled upon to return all combinations of a set of data. For example: if the data set happens to be ["ABCD", "ACDEF", "ABDFG", "BDEF", "CGEGD"], I would want the following in a list, that is, every unique element is combined with another unique element for a specified length.

A B C ,A B D ,A B E ,A B F ,A B G ,A C D ,A C E ,A C F ,A C G ,A D E ,A D F,A D G ,A E F ,A E G ,A F G ,B C D ,B C E ,B C F ,B C G ,B D E ,B D F ,B D G ,B E F ,B E G ,B F G ,C D E ,C D F ,C D G ,C E F ,C E G ,C F G ,D E F ,D E G ,D F G ,E F G

Here is my class thus far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

class Comboo {

    public static void combinationAssShit(String arr[], String data[], int start, int end, int index, int r){

    if (index == r)
     {
         for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
             System.out.print(data[j]+" ");

         System.out.println("");
         return;
     }

     for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i >= r-index; i++)
     {
         data[index] = arr[i];
         combinationAssShit(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
     }
 }

    public static void printCombination(String arr[], int n, int r)
    {
        String data[]=new String[r]; 
        combinationAssShit(arr, data, 0, n, 0, r);
    }

    public static String[] singleElem(String[] data) {
        List<String> single = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        for (String element: data) {
            for (int x = 0; x < element.length(); x++) {
                single.add(Character.toString(element.charAt(x)));
            }
        }

        Set<String> singleS = new LinkedHashSet<String>(single); 

        List<String> singleL = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        singleL.addAll(singleS); 

        String[] john = singleL.toArray(new String[singleL.size()]);
        return john;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String arr[] = {"ABCD", "ACDEF", "ABDFG", "BDEF", "CGEGD"};
        int r = 3;

        String[] t = singleElem(arr);
        int n = t.length;
        printCombination(t, n, r);
    }
}
```

Please note. I know there are a lot of corrections to be made. I am also brand new to Java. I am used to C++ and Python, which, in the case of this problem, is far easier in collecting the combinations in a list by yielding the result from the combo generator.

Comment: There is no result of a void function. That is the definition of void. You need to return an actual value (e.g. a String) to use it elsewhere.

Comment: i understand, which is the pressing problem here. Got any tips about how I should return a string in a recursive loop?

Comment: "I am used to C++ and Python, which, in the case of this problem, is far easier in collecting the combinations in a list by yielding the result from the combo generator." I'm curious to know what you mean by this. You should be able to do the same thing in Java.

Comment: for next in combinationAssShit(n, r-1) : yield combinationAssShit + next # args are diff

Comment: Oh, `yield`. Yes, Java definitely does not have `yield`, and I'm not sure if `return` is a drop-in replacement for you here or not. That said, C++ also does not have `yield`, so how would you implement it in C++?

Comment: Didn't do in C++. :'(

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is return the final result (string), you could throw all the code from your recursive procedure into another helper method and have the initial method call the helper and return the result.
Of course you'll also need to make both the recursive helper and your method not void in order to pass results via return.

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of the method to `List<String>`, and add values to the list:

```
public static List<String> combinationAssShit(String arr[], String data[], int start, int end, int index, int r){
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
  if (index == r) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j=0; j<r; j++) {
      sb.append(data[j]);
      sb.append(" ");
    }
    result.add(sb.toString());
  } else {
    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i >= r-index; i++)
    {
      data[index] = arr[i];
      result.addAll(combinationAssShit(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r));
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Alternatively, you can add the `List<String>` as a parameter to the method, so you don't have to keep on creating new instances:

```
public static void combinationAssShit(
    String arr[], String data[], int start, int end, int index, int r,
    List<String> result){
```

Comment: "... you can add the List<String> as a parameter to the method ..." I think in recursive programming this is sometimes called an "accumulator" variable.